# Grails Hql query for one to many association

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql, grails-orm

I have a Training domain class

```
    class Training {

     String type
     Date createdOn
     Date modifiedOn

    static belongsTo = [course: Course]
    static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]
  }
```

and i have Course domain class

```
     class Course {

          String name

          static hasMany = [trainings: Training, tracks: Track]
          static belongsTo = Track
   }
```

and Track domain class

```
    class Track {
        String name 
    }
```

Now  i have a filter (which is gsp page wich sends id's as a params to the control) that selects the training based on course and track

now say params.courseId = 1 and 3

so i write the query

```
   def query = "FROM Training AS t WHERE  t.course.id IN (1,3)"
   trainingList = Training.findAll(query)
```

which is correct i i get desired output.

now when i say i have track id's , params.trackId = 1,2

```
    def query = "FROM Training AS t WHERE  t.course.tracks.id IN (1,2)"
    trainingList = Training.findAll(query)
```

which is not working.. how to write the correct query where i have above said association.

Comment: Why not use "select t from Course c join c.trainings t where c.id in (1,2)".  Check samples here http://grails.asia/grails-hql-join-examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is your're querying one-to-many association, the "many" side.

Supposed HQL:

```
def query = "FROM Training AS t WHERE exists " +
  "(from t.course.tracks AS tr where tr.id IN (1,2))"
```

or criteria:

```
def trainings = Training.withCriteria {
   course {
     tracks {
       in('id', [1, 2])
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives Error:
Class : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Message: unexpected token: tr near line 1, column 75 [FROM com.mycompany.opal.Training AS t WHERE exists (SELECT track tr from t.course.tracks where tr.id IN (1,2))]

Comment: Updated. I didn't try it though, but should work. I'm pretty sure in the criteria though.

Comment: Can the list be extracted when there is no belongsTo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't went through much deeper but this query giving the same result like the query you written first

```
def trainingList = Training.findAll ("from Training as trnin "+
"join trnin.course.id as trinincr"+
"join trinincr.tracks.id"+
" where trnin.course.id in (1,3)")
```